# How to get the emerald sword?

Tags: the-gold-factory

At the beggining of the game the Enchanting Shop says, if you don't have diamond sword:

> **Enchanting Shop**
>   You can only enchant diamond and emerald sword, sorry :(

Since the game is supposed to be complete, how can the Emerald Sword be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get emerald sword by beating the invisible bot (you can battle with the invisible robot from the castle in the clouds)

Comment: The Castle in the clouds is reached by the plane?

Comment: Yes, you need to buy the plane and fly to reach it